# Accessing Labels in Widget in blogger.com

Tags: widget, conditional-statements, blogger, label

I want to display a widget only if the post contains specific label. Having issue with accessing the labels. data:post.labels is not working in if condition.

Answer (score 0):

use data:label.name for specific label in if condition.

```
<b:if cond='data:label.name == &quot;Oracle&quot;'>
...
</b:if>
```